# Docker: How to use overlay mount with host directory as upperdir?

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume

Basically, I want to do this:

```bash
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/opt/stable-diffusion-webui,upperdir=/mnt/overlay,workdir=/tmp/work /srv
```

Where `/opt/stable-diffusion-webui` is a directory in the container, it already contains files. These should not change (can probably be made readonly, but I'm not sure it matters).

`/mnt/overlay` is the directory I want to mount from my host file system. I'll come back to this in a sec.

`/tmp/work` is just something that overlayfs seems to need. Can use `tmpfs` for this I believe.

`/srv` is the combined directory. I want to run the app from there. The app likes to download and write files (also somewhere under /srv). I want these newly created files, and only these files (nothing from lowerdir), to show on my host file system.

I'm trying to run the container like this:

```
docker run -it  --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --rm --gpus=all -p 7860:7860 \
  --mount "type=tmpfs,dst=/tmp/work" \
  --mount "type=bind,src=$PWD/overlay,dst=/mnt/overlay,ro" \
  my-image
```

However, when I try run the `mount` command from inside the container I get:

> mount: /srv: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

All 4 directories exist in the container:

```
root@5e9d2dc5b109:/srv# ls /opt/stable-diffusion-webui /mnt/overlay /tmp/work /srv
/mnt/overlay:
file-on-host.txt

/opt/stable-diffusion-webui:
(bunch of files)

/srv:

/tmp/work:
```

How can I get this to work?